# How to unwrap a circular track

Tags: uv

For my banked road I sort of managed to make it look like it is a racing track.

I am really stuck with the pink part that is completely flat. I have a road texture and want to apply it to that, so that it follows the road

I think it should be easy but I don't know how to do it. I have searched but can't seem to find the right tutorial for this.

[image: My track]

Comment: I had another method to unwrap the circular mesh using a built-in addon in Blender 2.8. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41132/how-do-i-straighten-uv-maps/157014#157014

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Follow Active Quad UV unwrap option.

1. Click to select a segment of your track as the active face(s).
2. Tap A to select all other faces as well.
3. Press U to UV Unwrap and select Follow Active Quad

The track should be unwrapped properly with just a little adjustment needed.

[image]

Comment: 1.a Unwrap that Quad to UV  (Added it to your post but needs review.) It worked wonders for my ourside track as well. thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped!