# How to texture curved road system / road? (UV's / Mapping)

Tags: uv

So, to be brief, I am trying to create a system of roads from a top view of google maps.

[image: Google Maps]

I started out making the UV Map of the first segment and getting it in order, and hoping that when I extend the road the UV map would keep intact.

I can create the mesh fine, and as far as that goes, I have no problem. I am able to model it rather close to as seen on google maps, using extrude and rotate / translate.

I had the first section good at one point (of the road) but after that, the textures go weird. 
(Since then I have messed about and now nothing works properly, in regards to texture mapping which is when these pictures were taken.)

So, my biggest question, is, how can I add a road texture to this curved road, that will follow the road and the curves?

I would use the bezier curve method for road creation, but unfortunately, when exported to the game I intend to use the road for, the poly-count is tremendously high. 20000+ whereas with this method, 600-ish.

I guess, essentially, what I'm trying to do, is create roads like this:

[image]

[![Road/UV Windows][3]][3]

So how would I go about that, as far as texturing?

Comment: So, like now, I got the texture following the road, but, it's blurring, is there any way to remove the blur but keep it following the road? 
http://imgur.com/a/PIpOg

Comment: What did you try, and exactly what about the result did you not like? Please expand on "the textures go weird" with screenshots. A picture is worth 1,000 words.

Comment: I tried cube projection / uv re-map, and various methods to fix the texture blurring. 

http://imgur.com/a/1Ui8A

1st picture is blurring effect I don't like. (how the textures got, what I considered weird.)

2nd picture is texture after cube projection mapping. Also don't like that. 

Basically what I want is a nice smooth road texture that follows the road, not blurring or offsetting itself.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7553/create-a-road-along-large-terrain and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69115/how-to-curve-road-without-array-modifier and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25991/how-to-unwrap-a-circular-track

Comment: You're a genius! http://imgur.com/a/Iu0XC
The active quad thing did it! Looks great!
Thanks sooo much!